# UDF don't give the same result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers, user-defined-functions

when I exececute the UDF out of the trigger the result is not the same

the UDF return always true when executing in the trigger

but out of the trigger the result is true or false

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[MandatExist]
(
   @Numero      int,
   @IdBranche   int,
   @Exercice    int 
)
RETURNS   bit
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result   bit
    DECLARE @Nbr      int 
    DECLARE @Categ    int

    SELECT @Categ = CategorieNumero
    FROM Branche
    WHERE IdBranche = @IdBranche

    SELECT @Nbr=COUNT(*)
    FROM  Mandat AS M INNER JOIN Branche AS B ON M.IdBranche=B.IdBranche
    WHERE (Numero = @Numero) AND (B.CategorieNumero = @Categ) AND (Exercice = @Exercice)

    IF @Nbr = 0
      SET @Result = 0
    ELSE 
      SET @Result = 1

    RETURN @Result

END
```

the trigger call MandatExist to get if the number exist or not

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[ValidInsertUpdate_Mandat]
   ON  [dbo].[Mandat]
   FOR INSERT,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE  @Cloturer       AS bit
    DECLARE  @Exercice       AS int
    DECLARE  @IdBranche      AS int
    DECLARE  @Numero         AS int
    DECLARE  @Message        AS nvarchar(100)

    SELECT @Cloturer=Cloturer, @Exercice=Exercice, @Numero=Numero, @IdBranche=IdBranche
    FROM INSERTED


    IF (dbo.MandatExist(@Numero, @IdBranche, @Exercice)=1)
    BEGIN
      SET @Message = 'Numero de mandat existant.'
      RAISERROR(@Message, 16, 1)
      ROLLBACK TRAN
    END
```

Comment: Please append to the question a definition of UDF.

Comment: How are you calling the UDF from the trigger? What is the code for said trigger? What are the values of said data when it's called? We can't see what you see, so unless you show us we can't help.

Comment: `inserted` and `deleted` are tables so that they can represent the results of set operations. Designing a trigger on the assumption that it will always process exactly one row is generally a bad plan. If you are absolutely certain there will never be more than one row then _please_ add a check for the number of rows and use `RaIsError` or `Throw` to explicitly inform those who come along later that they have attempted to execute an unacceptable statement. (`if ( select Count(*) from inserted ) > 1 RaIsError( 'FooTable_Insert: No more than one row may be processed.', 25, 42 ) with log`)

Comment: Tip: When checking for the existence of one or more rows it is more efficient to use [`EXISTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) rather than getting an exact [`COUNT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx) and then just checking if it is greater than zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`INSERTED` is a table, thus may contain more than one row which means that this code

```
SELECT @Cloturer=Cloturer, @Exercice=Exercice, @Numero=Numero, @IdBranche=IdBranche
FROM INSERTED
```

is essentially incorrect.

UDFs are not the best choice for set-based programming and may cause performance degradation. Specifically this UDF makes absolutely no sense, has no reason for encapsulating this code into separate module. This is a trivial `EXISTS` code.

Entire function can and must be replaced by `EXISTS` statement, the whole code of the trigger might look like:

```
IF EXISTS(
  SELECT 1
  FROM INSERTED
  INNER JOIN ...
  WHERE ...
)
BEGIN
  RAISERROR(...)
END
```

I'm not sure what's the meaning of your tables and columns, but I assume you are trying to check some uniqueness. So, assuming that you don't want another `Mandat` record for the same `CategorieNumero`, the final EXISTS might look like:

```
IF EXISTS(
   SELECT 1
   FROM INSERTED i
   INNER JOIN Branch b on b.IdBranche = i.IdBranch
   -- other branches with the same CategorieNumero; why isn't CategorieNumero unique?
   INNER JOIN Branch b_dup on b_dup.CategorieNumero = b.CategorieNumero  
   -- existing Mandat rows for the same CategorieNumero with any IdBranch
   INNER JOIN Mandat m_dup on m_dup = b_dup.IdBranch 
   -- ensure you're not comparing inserted/updated Mandat row to itself
   WHERE i.ID != m_dup.ID 
)
...
```

But your intent is unclear to me and I think that after clarification most of your needs will be easily satisfied by **unique constraints**.

If you don't want more that one row for each set of `(Exercice, Numero, IdBranch)` - just add a unique constraint to `Mandat` table and drop both trigger and function!

Don't overuse triggers. And UDFs.

Answer (score 0):

i have used the solution of Ivan

```
IF EXISTS(
              SELECT 1
              FROM INSERTED I INNER JOIN Branche b ON b.IdBranche = i.IdBranche
                            INNER JOIN Branche b_dup ON b_dup.IdBranche = b.IdBranche
                            INNER JOIN Mandat m_dup on (m_dup.Exercice = i.Exercice) AND (m_dup.Numero = i.Numero) AND (b_dup.IdBranche=i.IdBranche) 
                            WHERE i.IdMandat != m_dup.IdMandat
             )
    BEGIN
      RAISERROR('error', 16, 1)
      ROLLBACK TRAN
    END
```